# To find the image of a complex function.

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z=x+iy$ and $f(z)=\frac{1}{z},z\ne 0$, then find the images of the following:
1) $x^2+y^2=3$
2)  $x\gt 0$.

I know the first one gives $z^2=3$, then surely f(z) is an analytic function with z not zero. I am not getting how should I find image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"find the images of the following" ... you mean "find the image of $f(z)$ under the following restrictions on its parameter $z$", right?

In that case, for 1.) you get $x^2 + y^2 = |z|^2 = 3$ or rather $z = \sqrt{3} \cdot e^{i\theta}$, so $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} e^{-i\theta}$, so the image of $f$ is
$$\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,e^{i\theta} \ | \ -\pi \leq  \theta < \pi \right\}$$
or rather
$$\left\{w \in \mathbb{C} \ \Big| \ |w| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right\} \ ,$$
the circle with radius $1/\sqrt{3}$ centered at $0$ in the complex plane.

For 2.), $\text{Re}\ z > 0$ means $z = |z| \cdot e^{i\theta}$ with $-\pi/2 <  \theta < \pi/2$, so $f(z) = \frac{1}{|z|} \cdot e^{-i\theta}$ has the same range of phase angles, i.e. also positive real part, and the image is thus the half-plane
$$\{w \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ \text{Re}\ w > 0 \} \ .$$

Comment: For 1) did you maybe mean $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \ldots\}$ and where do you get the intervall $-\pi \le \theta \lt \pi$ from?

Comment: @philmcole Yes you are right, your first point was an error on my side. The interval just sweeps all possible phase angles of complex numbers ($e^{i\theta}$ is $2\pi$-periodic).